# Should we add V20/M20 etc tags for White Wolf Games?

Tags: discussion, tags, world-of-darkness

In the recent years Onyx Path has released 20-year [anniversary editions of popular white wolf games](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Category:20th_Anniversary) which include both mechanical and plot/setting changes, like the removal of the metaplot that formed the World of Darkness in previous editions. To my knowledge, Vampire, Werewolf and, recently, Mage have been "updated" in this manner.
Currently the player base is split in mostly 3 fanbases,

- regular old World of Darkness (Vampire: the masquerade, 3rd/revised edition)
- Anniversary editions of oWoD without metaplot (V20/W20/M20)
- new World of Darkness products (Vampire: the requiem)

Further, a fourth group, for the upcoming 4th edition products that promise to take place subsequent to the events that "concluded" the earlier metaplots, seems likely to arise.

As such, I believe we should add tags ( [v20]/[m20]/[w20] or [vampire-20] maybe) for **each** of these games given the [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=v20) which already focus on them on the site. What do you think?

Comment: Note existing tagging structure for WoD: [Clean up tagging for “World of Darkness” related questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/clean-up-tagging-for-world-of-darkness-related-questions), where anniversary editions are discussed but everyone said "no unique tag needed".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are sufficiently distinct that someone who's watching [vampire-the-masquerade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade) would not be able to help a question about V20, then they should probably have separate tags. If they're close, then it could go either way and should probably wait on an obvious need.

If they should have separate tags, they should probably be [vampire-the-masquerade-20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade-20), etc. rather than just [v20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v20), though synonyms from the abbreviations would be good.

(And as usual, tags should/can only be created as-needed by existing questions, so if *Mummy 20th Anniversary* is in the works, no need or possibility to preemptively create a tag for it.)